# Why is my array (sql between date and date) is empty?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, date

I'm using Codeigniter.
I want to get in my database all the dates that are between two dates

**The result for my function is always an empty array.**
In my DB dates are this format: 2015-10-21

**My model**

```
public function lireListeAchats($selection = "*", $date_debut, $date_fin, $champs_order = "id", $direction_ordre = "ASC", $nombre_limite = NULL, $debut_limite = NULL){

$conditions = "date_achat BETWEEN $date_debut AND $date_fin";

$retour= $this->db->select($selection)
                    /*à partir de quelle table*/
                    ->from($this->table)
                    /*déterminer des conditions spécifiques*/
                    ->where($conditions)
                    /*déterminer un ordre précis*/
                    ->order_by($champs_order, $direction_ordre)
                    /*déterminer une limite*/
                    ->limit($nombre_limite, $debut_limite)
                    /*obtenir les résultats (va de pair avec result()*/
                    ->get()
                    /*retourner les résultats sous forme de tableau*/
                    ->result_array();

                    return $retour;

}
```

`$date_debut` and `$date_fin` return in this format: 2015-10-01

Comment: Are your dates *actually* stored as a `DATE` datatype, or as a `VARCHAR` in that format?

Comment: You are returning `$return` but your result array is stored in `$retour`.

Comment: also date $date_debut  should be less than $date_fin otherwise you will get nothing..

Comment: the date in the db are a DATE format

Comment: thanks for the return $retour... but my array is still empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of `$date_debut AND $date_fin`, those variables are strings.

Wrap them in quotes `'$date_debut' AND '$date_fin'`

MySQL is interpreting `2015-10-01` as 2015 minus 10 minus 01.

Use CodeIgniter's error checking:

- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: Merci beaucoup :) I hope my english was not so bad

Comment: @Véronique No, not at all (pas du tout) Véronique. J'ai bel et bien compris. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here. It should be either `return` or `retour`. **Return** seems to be better than retour.

```
public function lireListeAchats($selection = "*", $date_debut, $date_fin, $champs_order = "id", $direction_ordre = "ASC", $nombre_limite = NULL, $debut_limite = NULL){

$conditions = "date_achat BETWEEN $date_debut AND $date_fin";

$return= $this->db->select($selection)
                    /*à partir de quelle table*/
                    ->from($this->table)
                    /*déterminer des conditions spécifiques*/
                    ->where($conditions)
                    /*déterminer un ordre précis*/
                    ->order_by($champs_order, $direction_ordre)
                    /*déterminer une limite*/
                    ->limit($nombre_limite, $debut_limite)
                    /*obtenir les résultats (va de pair avec result()*/
                    ->get()
                    /*retourner les résultats sous forme de tableau*/
                    ->result_array();

                    return $return;
```

Comment: I fix it, but my array is still empty... even is $date_debut  come before $date_fin